# Call a function from an HTML page

Tags: javascript, function

I'm a beginner with JavaScript and I have a problem with one task:

An HTML page contains an element who's `id` attribute is "number". The page calls the function `countNelio()`, which should retrieve the contents of the element, calculate its square (second power), and print this to the console in the form "The square of X is Y". Create this function. That HTML page loads your code, so you can refer to the HTML page in your code with the word document.

```html
<body>
    <p id="number">0</p>
    <button id="button" onclick="countNelio()">Click here!</button>
</body>
```

In sample:

The square of chapter 12 is 144

Could someone help me? What kind of javascript code?

Comment: You need to create a global function called `countNelio` that takes the input `number` and squares it. That result will be printed to the console using `console.log`. You can write JavaScript code inside a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` of the HTML document, but you should probably put the `<script>` at the end of the `<body>`, so that your elements have rendered; or you can listen to the `DOMContentLoaded` event. Don't forget to add a `click` listener to your button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function in a `script` tag in the html, like so:

```
<script>
    function countNelio {
        const value = document.getElementById("number").textContent
        console.log(Math.pow(value, 2))
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank Luke very much. It worked great! I was in stuck here but not more...thanks again!!